# preg_replace match times variable php

Tags: php, preg-replace

Following idea

```
$aufnahme = "annaberg"; 
$i="2"; 
$zwei=preg_replace("/\A.{"$i"}/", ' ', $aufnahme);
```

It should remove only the number of the variable $i, of the the beginning word

means $i="2" //shows "naberg"

how can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty close, but your syntax is off:

```
$aufnahme = "annaberg"; 
$i="2"; 
$zwei=preg_replace("/\A.{".$i."}/", ' ', $aufnahme);
echo $zwei;
```

If you really just want to replace the first `$i` characters, just do `substr($aufnahme, $i);`

Answer (score 1):

Why not use substr()?

```
$aufnahme = "annaberg";
$zwei = substr($aufnahme, 2);
```

Will return "naberg" in this case..

Comment: i need a variable as 2-but thanks, good function (doesnt know about it)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this:

```
$aufnahme = "annaberg";
$i = "2";
echo substr($aufnahme, $i); // naberg
```